# Sum up combobox values using formulas in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Let's assume we have 2 fields - a tagfield (aka multiSelect combobox) and a textfield. The tagfield is populated from the underlying store having name and amount as parameters. On tagfield select I want to show corresponding amount into the textfield. If there are several fields have been selected from the tagfield I want to sum up the amount values.

There is no problem to implement that using tagfield onSelect listener:

```
onComboSelect: function(combo, recordArray) {
    var sum = recordArray.reduce(function(sum, record) {
        return sum + record.data.amount;
    }, 0);
    this.lookup('textfield').setValue(sum)
}
```

But I would like to give a try to MVVM formulas where I faced the following problems:

1. There is a 'delay' in one selected value between tagfield selection and populating textfield
2. There is no obvious way on how to sum up value with itself using the formulas.

Please see the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/20sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to `selection` behaves really strange. I would bind the formula to the tagfield `value`. It will provide an array with the selected record ids. Then in the viewmodel, you loop through them, get the related records, and sum their amounts. You will need a way to reference the store from the viewmodel. I solved this by moving the store declaration to the viewmodel.

Tagfield bindings:

```
bind: {
    value: '{tagValue}',
    store: '{tagStore}'
}
```

Viewmodel config:

```
viewModel: {
    formulas: {
        summedAmout: {
            bind: '{tagValue}',
            get: function (valueArray) {
                var sum = 0,
                    tagStore = this.getStore('tagStore');

                if (!valueArray.length) {
                    return '';
                }

                valueArray.forEach(function(tagId) {
                    sum += tagStore.getById(tagId).get('cost');
                });
                return sum;
            }
        }
    },
    stores: {
        tagStore: {
            data: [{
                id: 1, cost: 100, name: 'foo'
            }, {
                id: 2, cost: 200, name: 'bar'
            }]
        }
    }
},
```

Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2154&view/editor

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution works like a charm! Still for me viewmodel formulas are a bit tricky - that silent skipping whenever data is not set (even if the getter is commented) makes me unhappy.